# Open new tab based on comma-seperated array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

First off, Sorry if the question heading is a bit confusing. That is the best way I could frame this question.

The Main question is, I have a PHP script as below:

```
$variable = '1,12,16';
$myArray = explode(',', $variable);
foreach($myArray as $my_Array){ 
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
window.open('http://example.com/pages/"$my_Array".html', '_blank')</script>";
}
```

This piece of code should produce the following Output:

```
Open 3 new tabs
1st tab: 1.html
2nd tab: 12.html
3rd tab: 16.html
```

Any help Would be greatly appreciated!!

Also would be happy if anyone suggests a Better Title/Description for the question.

Comment: What is the current output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this change in your code

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  window.open('http://example.com/pages/".$my_Array.".html', '_blank') 
</script>"; //missed concatenation in $myarray variable
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are not concatenating your strings correctly. Here's what you should do:

```
$variable = '1,12,16';
$myArray = explode(',', $variable);
foreach($myArray as $my_Array){ 
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
window.open('http://example.com/pages/".$my_Array.".html', '_blank')</script>";
}
```

Comment: Gonna Test this out. Thanks. Will comment back.